# Pixel by pixel median of a list of 2D array - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of `numpy` 2D `ndarray` and I am trying to compute the "pixel by pixel" median and some percentile of all the dem of the list. Basically these are raster and I need to keep their dimensions. 
For example:

```py
A = [[1,1],[2,2]]
B = [[2,2],[3,3]]
C = [[3,3],[4,4]]
```

and I want:

```py
my_median = [[2,2],[3,3]]
```

I can do that in a "C-style" with for loops and eventually `cython` or `numba` to speed up the process as my arrays are quite big but I am pretty sure I am missing an easy and efficient way in `numpy`?

`np.median(np.sum([A,B,C]))` only gives me the global median or if I play with `axis` the median per row or col.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does np.median([A,B,C], axis=0) not give what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack the arrays in sequence depth wise and take the [`np.median`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) along the last axis:

```
np.median(np.dstack([A,B,C]), -1)

array([[2., 2.],
       [3., 3.]])
```